# O que são os arquivos .pyi do Python e para que servem?

Tags: python, tipagem

Reparei que na hora de criar um arquivo Python no PyCharm é oferecida uma opção "Python stub". Isso cria um arquivo .pyi. O que são esses arquivos e para que servem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*pyi* significa "*Python interface*". Interface, nesse sentido, é uma descrição dos tipos das funções, variáveis, classes etc. de um módulo, mas sem nenhuma implementação. Os *stub files* foram propostos na [PEP 484](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#stub-files), lançada pelo próprio criador do Python, que versa sobre inferência de tipos na linguagem.

Os arquivos .pyi são usados apenas pelo ambiente de desenvolvimento, eles não servem para ser executados (embora possam). As IDEs devem oferecer compatibilidade para esse recurso.

Seja `test.py` um módulo próprio ou de terceiros. Ao criar um arquivo `test.pyi` (a localização dele não importa, basta que a IDE esteja configurada para encontrá-lo), ele passará a oferecer inferência de tipos para o módulo de implementação. Por exemplo:

```
# test.py, o arquivo de implementação
def area_retangulo(base, altura):
    return base * altura
```

Só com essa sintaxe, não há indicação alguma de tipos. `base`, `altura` e o retorno da função são todos desconhecidos. No entanto, se tivermos um arquivo de interface:

```
# test.pyi, o arquivo de interface
def area_retangulo(base: float, altura: int) -> float: ...
```

A IDE automaticamente infere o tipo dos parâmetros e do retorno da função `area_retangulo` no módulo `test.py`. Repare que o arquivo .pyi não tem uma sintaxe especial, esta é meramente uma declaração de função que poderia ser feita num arquivo .py tradicional.

Segundo a própria especificação dos *stub files*, é recomendado que se use o operador [Elipsis](https://realpython.com/python-ellipsis/), que é as "reticências" (...), para não fornecer as implementações. Também é possível fornecer o tipo de variáveis (usando simplesmente `variavel: tipo`) e de métodos de classe.

Bem, os *stub files* não oferecem nenhuma funcionalidade a mais em relação ao que já é possível de se fazer sem eles. A proposta deles é melhorar a organização do código, visto que inferência de tipos pode tomar um espaço muito grande nos módulos. Além disso, eles também são usados para permitir a retrocompatibilidade do Python 3 para com o Python 2 sem que se perca a tipagem forte. Também é possível especificar a interface de uma biblioteca de terceiros que não a ofereça ainda.

Quem quiser usar os *stub files* no seu projeto deveria ler a seção dele (link no primeiro parágrafo), que contém diversos detalhes bem específicos de como usá-los.